# Two circles X and Y with centres A and B intersect at C and D. If area of circle X is 4 times area of circle Y, then AB=?

Tags: circles

This question is solved by taking angleACB = 90 in my book. How can we say that this angle a right angle triangle? Given answer is √5r.

Comment: There must be a drawing that goes with this.  The angle between a radius and the tangent at the point the radius hits the circle is a right angle, does that do what you need?  Without further information I don't see how we answer this.

Answer (score 0):

You need information because you can put the circles so that it intersect and $AB$ can vary. I suppose that $\angle ACB =90^\circ$ is hypothesis.

Comment: Question is given with four option and in solution ACB=90 [ angle at the point of intersection to the center of the circles.] is written.

Answer (score 0):

By the triangle inequality $$AC+CB>AB$$ or
$$2r+r>AB$$ or $$AB<3r.$$
Now, by the triangle inequality again we obtain
$$AB+r>2r,$$ which gives
$$r<AB<3r.$$